# iPhone - vectorial format for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone

What is the best vectorial format I can use to create resolution independent vectorial artwork for iPhone and iPad? PDF?

I have to draw large images 1024x1300 images on a quartz context. Suppose I use PDF. What technique would save more memory and consume less CPU: have the PNG image loaded and draw it on the quartz context or have the PDF loaded on the quartz context?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Opacity image editor allows you to draw vector graphics, and output Quartz2D code that you can then use to duplicate the image at any size on any iOS device:

http://likethought.com/opacity/

It would be blazing fast and use almost no memory (well, a large CALayer will consume memory)

Comment: wow, fantastic the stuff this app can do. It has functions I wish Adobe Photoshop had for years! Filters on layers, effects on layers, amazing! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As usual 'it depends'.

Using PNGs of that size will require 5MB of memory to keep them uncompressed in a buffer. This may be fine for your app.

Memory usage of a PDF document is very dependent on the complexity of that document. In my experience vector graphics and text are pretty efficient. Specially when rendered to a Layer.

I think you will simply have to put together a small proof-of-concept app and run it in Instruments to get some real numbers.